# AppStore submission stuck on processing Preview movie

Tags: app-store-connect

I submitted a new App yesterday and included a video preview file for several size devices (6.7, and a copy of 6.7 for 6.5, 5.5 and 12.9).
The iPhone files each took 5-10 minutes of processing (where the file icon shows a cloud image) but each eventually worked.  The iPad file uploaded fine, but now 18 hours later is still showing a cloud icon.
All these uploaded files are about the same size at about 40M.
The AppStore will not allow me to submit the App for review due to:
Preview File Still Processing!

What is my recourse?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now moot!  21 hours and the preview file finally finished processing! 21 hours to process a 43Meg file!